# Powershell Invoke-Command adds NoteProperty PSComputerName and exception handling

Tags: powershell

I am iterating over an array of hostnames and need to check to see what version of PowerShell they are running. If the check fails (machine off, no PowerShell, not configured for remoting, etc...), then I will want to produce a message that the the query of the host failed.

Even though `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` does not have a `PSComputerName` property, it appears that `Invoke-Command` adds it as a `NoteProperty`.

In order to handle the fail condition, I create a new `System.Version` object and add a `PSComputerName` `NoteProperty` to it. Is this the best OO or PowerShell way to do this? Is there something better or more succinct?

```
Try {
    $v = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $thishost {$PSVersionTable.PSVersion} -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch
{
    $v = New-Object -TypeName "System.Version"
    $v | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PSComputerName -Value "$thishost connect failed"
}
$v
```

The output looks something like:

```
"BUFFALO","98b47c10-3dcf-4da2-xxxx-xxxx335c7daa","True","2","0","-1","-1","-1","-1"
"BISON","79d4d003-d740-4474-xxxx-xxxx7d801b3a","True","2","0","-1","-1","-1","-1"
"ZEBRA connect failed",,,"0","0","-1","-1","-1","-1"
"WOLF connect failed",,,"0","0","-1","-1","-1","-1"
"FUGU","b26f0c5c-1549-411b-xxxx-xxxxef53ecce","True","5","0","10586","117","0","117"
```

Comment: I think the most powershell-idiomatic approach would be to keep standard output and error messages separate